# How do I fix a missing forward slash in link_to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I am learning to use haml in rails 4.

I added this line to my 'demo/index.html.haml' file:

```
= link_to 'Hello with parameters',:controller => 'demo', :action => 'hello', :id=> 21, :page => 5
```

The resulting html output is missing a slash between the string hello and 21 like this:

```
<a href="/demo/hello21?page=5">Hello with parameters</a>
```

I am not sure why the forward slash is missing.

My Gemfile has this:

```
 gem 'haml-rails'
```

Please tell me if I can provide more information to help troubleshoot this.

I am running:

- windows 7
- ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
- Rails 4.2.2
- haml (4.0.7)
- haml-rails (0.9.0)
- html2haml (2.0.0)

Thank you in advance.

### EDIT

I was asked about my route.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'demo#index'
  # Default Route
  match ':controller(/:action(:id(.:format)))', :via => :get
end
```

And when I run rake routes I get:

```
$ rake routes
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
  root GET  /                                     demo#index
       GET  /:controller(/:action(:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
```

Comment: Maybe a bug in your route? How did you define the route?

Comment: Another pointer: Rails generates path helper methods. In your case I'd expect `hello_demo_path(21)` to be available. `rake routes` will list them (without the _path postfix).

Comment: @Raffael I added my route.rb file to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash is already missing in your route. Add it after `:action` like so:

`match ':controller(/:action/(:id(.:format)))', :via => :get`

Comment: Also, please do not use this generic match pattern in production. It will expose all public controller methods as actions and that might introduce security risks. It is completely fine while just tinkering around, though.

Comment: Also, you may abbreviate this as `get ':controller(/:action/(:id(.:format)))'`

Comment: Thank you for your help and advise. I will put it to use.